# I'm trying to make a function CodeIgniter framework so I can search products through my database

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, codeigniter-3

Good day! I'm trying to make a function on the CodeIgniter framework so I can search products through my phpMyAdmin database but I'm getting an error.

Some database info:

```
db name: kadokado
db table: products
db table column name: product_naam
```

My view file (result_view.php):

```
    <h1>Zoek een cadeau</h1>
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action=" {{ base_url }}search/search_keyword" method = "post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name = "keyword"size="30px; ">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value = "Search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

My controller file (SearchController.php) :`

```
<?php


class SearchController extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
         $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
    }

    function search_keyword()
{
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results']    =   $this->mymodel->search($Keyword);
}


}`
```

My model file (Keyword.php) :`

```
<?php



class Keyword extends CI_model  {

    function search($keyword)
{
    $this->db->like('product_naam',$keyword);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('products');
    return $query->result();
}





}


?>
`
```

The PHP error that I'm receiving when I load the view:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: controllers/SearchController.php

Line Number: 9

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/SearchController.php
Line: 9
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

And this is the error when i click on my search button:

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

I hope someone can help me so this function can work properly.
Thanks!

Comment: first edit your 'action="<?= base_url('search/search_keyword')?>"'..you are not using blade template right?

Comment: Hey I changed it to : <?= base_url('search/search_keyword')?> and it still says : page not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined `$data` variable in controller.

```
public function index(){
         $data = array();
         $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
    }
```

In your controller page please load model first than use model function.

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $this->load->model('Keyword');
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results']    =   $this->Keyword->search($Keyword);
}
```

In your model part check function describe below.

```
function search($keyword)
{
    $this->db->select('product_naam');
    $this->db->like('product_naam',$keyword);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('products');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Hey the first error is removed! thanks for that. But it still says page not found when I click on search

Comment: When you click on search button which url you got in browser..? Please share URL.

Comment: In your search form please change action from `action=" {{ base_url }}search/search_keyword"` to `action=" {{ base_url }}SearchController/search_keyword"`

Comment: Hello I did and now when I click on search i get these 2 errors: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: SearchController::$Search_model

Filename: controllers/SearchController.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/SearchController.php
Line: 15
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: and I also get this error when I click on search: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function search() on a non-object

Filename: controllers/SearchController.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:

Comment: Thx it somehow works now but can you explain to me how I can ONLY see the name of the products when i search something instead of seeing all this: Array ( [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 1 [product_naam] => Tennisracket [product_beschrijving] => Een mooie tennisracket van hout [user_id] => 0 [product_categorie] => kinderspeelgoed [ophaal_plaats] => Rotterdam-Zuid [product_foto] => 542y6i8a.jpg [date_created] => 2017-06-07 [date_updated] => 2017-06-07 ) ) )

Comment: echo $data['result'][0]->product_naam. You will get the Name of the products.

Comment: @frodo : Glad to help  you.

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined the $data variable in your controller

```
class SearchController extends CI_Controller {

  public function index() {
    $this->load->view('result_view');
  }

  function search_keyword() {
    $this->load->model('Search_model');
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results'] = $this->Search_model->search($Keyword);
    print_r($data);
  }
}
```

**Your Model**

```
class Search_model extends CI_model  {

 function search($keyword) {
   $this->db->like('product_naam', $keyword);
   $query = $this->db->get('products');
   return $query->result();
 }
}
```

**View**

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="<?php echo base_url('SearchController/search_keyword'); ?>" method = "post">
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name = 
  "keyword"size="30px; ">
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value = "Search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```